# Displaying contents of a pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf

When echoing out file_get_contents on an uploaded pdf file, I get a load of nonsense displayed like so:

> 6}ÕìúÖ

Is there anyway of decoding this infomation?

Comment: What did you expect? A PDF has a binary file format, and its contents is *never* only plain text that you can read on a console. Even if it's not compressed, there are loads of infrastructure in and around the supposedly "plain" text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this Code maybe help you

```
<?php
 $file = 'path/to/PDF/file.pdf';
 $filename = 'filename.pdf';
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 @readfile($file);
```

?>

be successfull

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read/alter the contents of the pdf file you have to use a library like [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

If you want to show the pdf you have to set the correct content type:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline;');
echo file_get_contents('yourpdf.pdf');
```

(readfile is a better option though)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://www.fpdf.org/

It's a library that has also been suggested in other questions identical to this.

Comment: "Let the browser know that a PDF file is coming." - what browser? He is trying to read the pdf file, not sending it to the client.

Comment: Oh you're right I completely read this wrong! @user4035 I'll update answer to just the library.